# COUNT number of wins and MAX participant with the most wins with MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, max

I have a table called `games` with the fields: `match` and `winner`.

- `Match` is a foreign key to the `matches` table;
- `winner` is a foreign key to the 'participants' table that can be `NULL` if the game is still undecided.

I need a way to find out who won each match when I select a list of matches by counting who won each game and returning the participant (from the winner field) who had the most wins.

Various combinations of subqueries, `GROUP BY`, `COUNT`, and `MAX` have yet to give me the right results.

I don't think I can substitute `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` for `MAX` because that would return just the first participant in a match if all participants happened to have the same number of wins.

Comment: So, if there are more than one participants with same number of wins, what it should be returned?

Comment: Could you post a dump of the two tables with some record for make a test?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using JOINs with GROUP BY and COUNT ?

```
select b.name, count(c.match)
from game a
inner join part b on a.winner = b.winner
inner join matches c on a.match = c.match
group by b.winner;
```

John